# Writerow coma separates the items I pass to him don't know why

Tags: python

I have la list: final_data = ['0.0267166', '0.0534331', '0.0801497', '0.106866', ...]

I'm trying to write this data into .csv file with csv module from python (no pandas allowed)

so I'm using this code from documentation

```
with open('final_data.csv', 'w+', newline='') as f:
    f = open('final_data.csv', "w+")
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for item in final_data:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

but the resulting csv is coma separated by character inside each row :S

result:
[image: openoffice]

I was expecting every item written as it is in each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
import csv

final_data = ['0.0267166', '0.0534331', '0.0801497', '0.106866']
final_data = [[e] for e in final_data]

with open(r'path_to_your_outputCsv.csv', 'w', newline="\n") as f:
    wr = csv.writer(f)
    wr.writerow(['final_data'])
    wr.writerows(final_data)
```

##### # Output (.csv) :

```
final_data
0.0267166
0.0534331
0.0801497
0.106866
```